# How is video streamed in HTML5 video?

Tags: http, tcp, udp, streaming, html5-video

I would like to know how HTML5 video in `<video>` tags is streamed to the Browser. Is it an HTTP stream and therefore TCP or is it UDP (which I don't think based on things I read so far)

and maybe also, which role may QUIC take to change the streaming of video in HTML5 if any?

Answer (score 1):

From our experience of [Nimble HTTP Streamer](https://wmspanel.com/nimble) development I can say for sure that in modern browsers like Chrome or Firefox the HTML5 player accepts progressive download via HTTP GET. It also supports seeking of position based on HTTP Range header.

So it's HTTP and TCP.

To make it play something else like RTMP or HLS you need to build something on top, like [JWPlayer team](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) does.